# Using multiple Textures with geometry.faceVertexUvs

Tags: three.js

I want to use multiple materials and multiple textures on meshes. I use 3 materials and a `geometry.faceVertexUvs` with two arrays of Uvs. One arrayof UVs for the first texture and one array of UVs for the second texture. However that doesn't quite work. Three.js always uses the uvs of the first array and `geometry.faceVertexUvs[1]` is never used. Do I have to put all the uvs in `geometry.faceVertexUvs[0]` for both textures or does it work differently? And if I have to put all uvs in `geometry.faceVertexUvs[0]` then I wonder why `geometry.faceVertexUvs` is an array at all. Explanation would be great. The Three.js documentation is not very detailed there.

here my sample code and tanks guys! Tom

```
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(60, 60, 60);

    var texture1 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "../sons.png" );
    var texture2 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "../Richard-branson.jpg" );

    var material0 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color:0xffff00});
    var material1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map:texture1,  shininess:100});
    var material2 =  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map:texture2,  shininess:100});

    for(var i=0; i< geometry.faces.length;i++){
        geometry.faces[i].materialIndex = i%3;
        geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][i][0] = new THREE.Vector2(0,0);
        geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][i][1] = new THREE.Vector2(1,0);
        geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][i][2] = new THREE.Vector2(0,1);

        geometry.faceVertexUvs[1]= [];
        geometry.faceVertexUvs[1][i] = [];
        geometry.faceVertexUvs[1][i][0] = new THREE.Vector2(1,1);
        geometry.faceVertexUvs[1][i][1] = new THREE.Vector2(1,0);
        geometry.faceVertexUvs[1][i][2] = new THREE.Vector2(0,1);
    }


    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, [material0, material1, material2]);
    view.scene.add(mesh);
    view.render();
```

Comment: meanwhile I implemented it by putting all in geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] which works. Still wonder why there is a geometry.faceVertexUvs[1]... Would be interesting to learn

Comment: I'm also wondering the answer to this particular question